# Loading bar across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a scenario where I am needing to incorporate a progress bar. (This not being the problem). The problem comes in here:

This progress bar needs to continue across different page calls until I hit a specific page.

So basically, it looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="processing_overlay">
  <div class="abs">#labelProcessing#<br>
    <img src="/defaultStyles/images/transparent-ajax-loader.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
     $('##processing_overlay').show();
     setTimeout(function() { $('##processing_overlay').hide(); }, 5000);
</script>
<cfinclude template="/nextpage">
```

So essentially when it goes to the next page, the progress bar would need to carry on. I've searched high and low for any possibility of getting this right but without any success.

Any ideas of how I could possibly get around this?

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to use something to pass the progress bars percentage across pages. The quickest and easiest way is to just set a cookie and update it before the page leaves to go to the next page. Then clear it once the progress bar is done.

Comment: Is the bar a gif image? Looking at the code it looks like so. If that is the case then you can have n number of gif images, each starting from a different start points based on the page number. Like on page 1 the gif will start from 0 - 100, on page 2 25-100, on page 3 40-100, and so on. If you are using div based loading bar then you will have to pass on the starting point for each page, via cookie or GET parameter.

Comment: So store the value [cookies/localstorage] when it changes. When the page loads, set the start value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loading bar is in reference to the number of pages being processed another simpler way to do it is this:

Page1.cfm

```
<cfset session.totalPages = 5>

<cfset currentPage = 1>

<div width="100%">
    <div width="#round(currentpage/session.totalPages)#%"></div>
</div>
```

Page2.cfm

```
 <cfset currentPage = 2>
```

and so on. You'll have to style the divs appropriately to get the right look of a loading bar.

Comment: Thanks all for your contribution. I have successfully got this working.